# Dataset - Fama French Replication

Tags: finance, asset-pricing, replication

I am trying to replicate the Fama-French three-factor model. I am having issues in the dataset.

1) Using the CRSP/COMPUSTAT merged dataset for firm fundamentals from WRDS, and then dropping data on financial and non-US firms, I have much fewer firms than what FF have in the dataset in French's website. Any suggestions on why this is happening?

2) I am unable to obtain data as far back as 1926 from WRDS.

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: Have you seen this previous thread? https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/10699/question-on-fama-french-three-factor-model Does it help you?

Comment: Yes, I did. I am aware of French's website but I want to be able to download the data by myself and match their calculations of the factors.